# CSS: Style applied to a combination of classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm not sure this is possible, but is there a syntax to be used in CSS when you want to style an element based on the combination of classes applied to it?

I understand that I can check an element with jQuery or something and change it's style based on the classes it has, but is there a pure CSS way to do this?

For example, if I have a class for bold and green:

```
.bold_green { color:green; font-weight:bold; }
```

And a class for bold and blue:

```
.bold_blue { color:blue; font-weight:bold. }
```

Now, say I am using jQuery to add and remove classes dynamically and want any element that has both classes to turn italic pink.

Something like:

```
.bold_green AND .bold_blue { color:pink; font-style:italic; }
```

Or, if I want to style an element that has aclass, and is a descendant of another element that has another class?

Something like:

```
.bold_green HAS_CHILD .bold_blue { color:black; background-color:yellow; }
```

Thanks!

**Edit**

Thanks for all the answers.  These are pretty much what I thought (just treating the classes as regular selectors), but they don't seem to be working for me.  I will have to check my code and make sure they aren't being overridden somehow...

Comment: Didn't you mean to use `color: blue` in the `bold_blue` class?

Comment: as a sidenote, if you have classes like `bold_green`, then there's probably something wrong with the way you're designing. <insert semantics spiel>

Comment: Dude.  It's an example.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
$('.bold_green.bold_blue').addClass('something-else');
```

Or in CSS:

```
.bold_green.bold_blue { color: pink; }
```

Notice there's no space between the selectors.

Comment: There are IE compatibility issues though, no?

Comment: Yes, IE6 will read that css as .bold_blue { color: pink; }. You should use a variation of the jQuery Paul provided since jQuery can select it properly, and add a new class with appropriate css: .something-else { color: pink; } I also hope those aren't real class names.

Comment: Ideally, you add the CSS as recommended here first, and then add the jQuery mentioned inside a conditional comment for IE6.

Comment: Hrm, mentioned here ... http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html ... 'To match a subset of "class" values, each value must be preceded by a ".".'

Answer (score 6):

You don't need anything special, just

```
.bold_green.bold_blue { color:pink; font-style:italic; }
```

Answer (score 5):

[Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451399/css-style-applied-to-a-combination-of-classes/2451401#2451401) and [Voyager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451399/css-style-applied-to-a-combination-of-classes/2451416#2451416) are correct for the multiple classes case.

For the "HAS CHILD" case you would use:

```
.bold_green .bold_blue { ... } /* note the ' ' (called the descendant selector) */
```

Which will style any `bold_blue` elements inside a `bold_green` element.

Or if you wanted a DIRECT child:

```
.bold_green > .bold_blue { ... } /* this child selector does not work in IE6 */
```

Which will style only `bold_blue` elements which have an immediate parent `bold_green`.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio 2013 the CSS setting is applied to multiple classes by a "Comma" as follows:

`.bold_green, .bold_blue { color:pink; font-style:italic; }`