# Define CSS for input, using style class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to define a css rule that applies to all input fields of a given style class ("beveledInput"). For example, when writing this xhml code :

```
<p:inputText value="#{filtersBean.titleLike}" styleClass="beveledInput" />
```

this is the resulting html code

```
<input type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all beveledInput" name="_xyz_WAR_xyz_:j_idt5:j_idt33" id="_xyz_WAR_xyz_:j_idt5:j_idt33" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
```

So far I've managed to define this css style,

```
.aui input[type="text"], 
.aui input[type="search"], 
.aui textarea, 
.aui 
.uneditable-input {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #333333;
    height: 12.5px;
    width: 220px;
}
```

but of course it's getting applied to all inputfields, and that's not what I really need.

How can I get this style applied **only** when using the `beveledInput` css class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [combination of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451399/css-style-applied-to-a-combination-of-classes) in CSS

```
.aui input[type="text"].beveledInput, 
.aui input[type="search"].beveledInput, 
.aui textarea.beveledInput, 
.aui .uneditable-input.beveledInput {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #333333;
    height: 12.5px;
    width: 220px;
}
```

Comment: @yannicular. JSF/PrimeFaces is in case just an html generator, so it is actually not PrimeFaces related but plain html/css. Might be good to get to grips with some basic css knowledge before advancing

Comment: @Kukeltje I agree, I should study some css. Thanx for your honest advice.

Comment: @kukeltje. But since I'm writing an xhtml code with (not html) and I'm restricted from the way the p facelets are generating the html code, I dont't think that the  `primefaces` reference was totally irrelevant. While I do understand this is a css issue, the `primefaces` tag could at least bring the attention to someone who could additionally provide me a primefaces-specific best practice

Answer (score -1):

Try this as an example:

Apply CSS style

```
<style>
        .inputText{
            color: blue !important;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border-color: #333333;
            height: 12.5px;
            width: 220px;
        }
</style>
```

And Primefaces component

```
<p:inputText styleClass="inputText" />
```